# How to search and replace using regular expressions in Visual Studio

Tags: search, visual-studio-2012, replace

I need to replace all the urls with empty string:

```
""regular"": ""http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abhayalibre/v3/zTLc5Jxv6yvb1nHyqBasVy3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf"",
""500"": ""http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abhayalibre/v3/wBjdF6T34NCo7wQYXgzrc5MQuUSAwdHsY8ov_6tk1oA.ttf"",
""600"": ""http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abhayalibre/v3/wBjdF6T34NCo7wQYXgzrc2v8CylhIUtwUiYO7Z2wXbE.ttf"",
""700"": ""http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abhayalibre/v3/wBjdF6T34NCo7wQYXgzrc0D2ttfZwueP-QU272T9-k4.ttf"",
""800"": ""http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abhayalibre/v3/wBjdF6T34NCo7wQYXgzrc_qsay_1ZmRGmC8pVRdIfAg.ttf""
```

I've tried using the Regular Expressions with:

"http://fonts(*).ttf"

but i can't see the replace working.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the vs2012 tag is correct? Looks a lot like 2015 or 2017 in the screenshot.

Comment: yes i'm sure, It's Visual Studio Professional 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is `(*)`, use instead:

```
http://fonts.+\.ttf
```

Answer (score 1):

[Regular Expression Search and Replace is actually quite well documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx).

At the moment you're matching strings that look like this, unless Visual Studio actually fails to parse the expression because of the incorrect usage of *.

```
http://font).ttf
http://font().ttf
http://font(().ttf
http://font(((().ttf
http://font((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((().ttf
etc
```

To match any character you could use `.*`, `.` being the universal match in Regex, but that will match beyond the closing quotes.

Instead, you can use `[^"]+` to match one or more characters except `"`.

```
http://font\.[^"]+
```

Also, note the `\.` to make sure the regex actually matches the `.` character, the `\` escapes it from being the universal match character.