# Renaming all subclasses of a given class in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, rename

I'm fixing naming conventions in a massive .NET C# solution. I have a base class, let's call it DtoBase, that I'm renaming to ViewModelBase. I need to rename the classes that inherit the base class like so:

```
FooDto -> FooViewModel
BarDto -> BarViewModel
BazDto -> BazViewModel
```

You get the idea. Problem is there's about a hundred of those classes, and doing it manually would take forever. I need a proper rename, one that will update all the references. Is there a Visual Studio function/tool/plugin that could do this? I have ReSharper but am not very familiar with it. Is there a way to do this in ReSharper?

Alternatively, I could do a full text search&replace. I can't just replace every instance of "Dto" with "ViewModel", that would cause mayhem. But I can get a list of all the names to replace, and then do them one by one, replacing "FooDto" with "FooViewModel" and so on. Notepad++ for instance can do this. But that would still mean manually running 100 commands. I would like some tool I can feed a list of value pairs that will run "replace in files" for each of them. Maybe some sort of command line tool? I would then need a similar process to rename the files.

Comment: Have you tried using [search and replace in Visual Studio using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47261952/how-to-search-and-replace-using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio)?

Comment: You will not be able to rename the files themselves, so you need to do an external script or do this manually